# Words implied after saying "終わりだ。何も。" in footage of the Mar. 2011 tsunami?

Tags: grammar

In [video footage](https://youtu.be/eeLlySDmjuw?t=2m40s) of the tsunami in March, 2011, someone said while watching the beginning of the destruction of a harbor:

> 終わりだ。何も。

Is he thinking

> 終わりだ。何も*残らない*。

So the correct translation is:

> This is the end of everything here. Nothing will remain.

To inject explicit "future tense", could I say something like this:

> 終わりだ。何も残らなさそうだ。

But that "future tense" Japanese sounds stilted and weird even in writing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the guy is actually saying 「終わりだ、なにも」, which is almost ungrammatical. Perhaps he was too exited to say the sentence until the end. I guess the person would have wanted to say 「終わりだ、何もかも」, which is the same as 「何もかも終わりだ」 ("Everything is over/finished"). We don't have to think of the verb 残らない here.

In addition, 何も残らなそうだ (="It seems that ...") is too long and a person in a situation like this would not say something like that.

Answer (score 4):

> 終わりだ。何も。

Your guess may be right, but mine is different:

> 終わりだ。*何もかも*。

However, I think your translation is still correct.

---

> 終わりだ。何も残らなさそうだ。

This future tense sounds natural and has no problem both in speaking and in writing.

But it might not match that situation. The speaker should not be in such a mental condition that he can make a guess about future.